# How can I turn a popup menu invisible?

Tags: menu, openedge, progress-4gl, popupmenu

I'm working with Progress release 11.6, appBuilder and procedure editor.

I'm creating a new window, based on another one. That other window contains a browser, on which a popup menu is attached.
In my copy I don't want to see the popup menu at this moment (in other words, I'd like to disable it, so that the user does not see it).

I have tried putting `VISIBLE` to `FALSE`, `HIDDEN` to `TRUE`, but I'm always getting into problems.

My code looks as follows, does anybody know how I can turn the popup-menu invisible?

```
DEFINE MENU popup-menu-browser
       MENU-ITEM m_Copy LABEL "Copy" ACCELERATOR "CTRL-C"
       MENU-ITEM m_Cut  LABEL "Cut"  ACCELERATOR "CTRL-X"
       ...

browser-object:POPUP-MENU = MENU popup-menu-browser:HANDLE

// not working:
MENU POPUP-MENU-browser:HIDDEN = TRUE.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the popup-menu:

```
MENU POPUP-MENU-browser = ?.
```

Or make it insensitive:

```
MENU POPUP-MENU-browser:SENSITIVE = FALSE.
```

Complete example:

```
define browse br with size 40 by 10.

define menu mb
   menu-item mhide label "Hide"
   .

on choose of menu-item mhide do:
   browse br:popup-menu:sensitive = false.
end.   

on " " anywhere do:
   browse br:popup-menu:sensitive = true.
end.
   
browse br:popup-menu = menu mb:handle.

define frame fr 
   br
with 
   size 42 by 12 
   view-as dialog-box
   .

enable all with frame fr.
view frame fr.
wait-for close of frame fr.
```

Beware that when switching between popup menus, you will lose the values of check boxes - see knowledge base article [000054795](https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Knowledge/000054795)

Comment: I try to avoid removing the menu, because, when I do that, the appBuilder removes it all together (menu items included), which is exactly what I want to avoid.

Comment: Which is why you need to save the handle.

Comment: Maybe easier just to use the sensitive attribute.